Roblox Studio Anti-Noclip Script
I've been trying to make an Anti-Noclip script, but it doesn't work too well. Could someone help me or tell me what's wrong and how to fix it?
This is the code I currently have:
local function CheckNoclip(previous_pos: CFrame, current_pos: CFrame, player: string)
    local raycastResult = workspace:Raycast(current_pos, previous_pos)
    
    local char = workspace:FindFirstChild(player)
    
    if raycastResult then
        print("Instance:", raycastResult.Instance)
        print("Position:", raycastResult.Position)
        print("Distance:", raycastResult.Distance)
        print("Material:", raycastResult.Material)
        print("Normal:", raycastResult.Normal)
    end
    
    if raycastResult then
        if raycastResult.Instance.CanCollide == true and (not (raycastResult.Instance:IsDescendantOf(char)) ) then
            local Physical_Part = workspace:FindFirstChild(player)
            local RootPart = Physical_Part:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
            
            RootPart.CFrame = CFrame.new(previous_pos)
            warn("No-Clip Found")
        end
        print("---------------------------------")
    end
end

local players = game.Players

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr: Player)
    local player_name = plr.Name
    plr.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    local RootPart = workspace:FindFirstChild(player_name).HumanoidRootPart
    local prev_position = RootPart.CFrame.Position
    local current_position = prev_position
    
    while true do
        current_position = RootPart.CFrame.Position
        if prev_position ~= current_position then
            CheckNoclip(prev_position, current_position, player_name)
            prev_position = current_position
        end
        wait()
    end
end)

This keeps happening: https://youtu.be/5hF6SoNxX08 (I uploaded it as an unlisted youtube video)

Heyo, an important piece of information for us is "why doesn't your script work well?"
Did you test it by noclipping, and your script simply didn't catch it? What part of the script is failing?

Right, Sorry, I forgot to add a recording. I added a youtube link with the issue I'm experiencing. @Kylaaa

The problem is that you gave the wrong parameters the :Raycast() method. the function needs an Orgin and Direction not a Start And End you can calculate the Direction between these 2 vectors by doing CurrPos - LastPos.
note that this could possible false flag because of lag or ping since its serversided.
local exclude = {}

local function CheckNoclip(LastPos: Vector3, CurrPos: Vector3, Player: Player)
    if CurrPos == LastPos then return; end

    local Orgin = LastPos;
    local Direction = CurrPos - LastPos;
    local Params = RaycastParams.new();
    Params.FilterDescendantsInstances = exclude;
    Params.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Exclude;
    
    local Result = workspace:Raycast(Orgin, Direction, Params);

    if not Result then return; end
    if not Result.Instance.CanCollide then return; end
            
    local Character = Player.Character;
    local Root = Character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart");

    Root.CFrame = CFrame.new(LastPos);
    warn("No-Clip Found");
    print("---------------------------------");
end

game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player: Player)

    Player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(Character)
        table.insert(exclude, Character);
        
        local Humanoid = Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid");
        local Root = Character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart");
        
        local CurrPos = Root.Position;
        local LastPos = CurrPos;
        
        task.spawn(function() -- create loop in new thread
            repeat 
                LastPos = CurrPos;
                CurrPos = Root.Position;
                
                CheckNoclip(LastPos, CurrPos, Player);
                task.wait();
            until Humanoid.Health <= 0
        end)
    end);
    Player.CharacterRemoving:Connect(function(Character)
        table.remove(exclude, table.find(exclude, Character));
    end);
end)

